Инициализация нескольких яндекс карт
Вот html
<div class="map"  data-long="50.6106903" data-lat="36.5612213" data-zoom="13"></div>
<div class="map"  data-long="51.6106903" data-lat="36.5612213" data-zoom="13"></div>
<div class="map"  data-long="52.6106903" data-lat="36.5612213" data-zoom="13"></div>

Вот JavaScript
var counter=0;
var mapZoom;
var lat;
var long;
$(".map").each(function() {
    counter++;
    $(this).attr("id", 'map'+counter);
    mapZoom = $("#map"+counter).attr("data-zoom");
    lat = $("#map"+counter).attr("data-lat");
    long = $("#map"+counter).attr("data-long");
    ymaps.ready(function () {        
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map'+counter, {
            center: [long, lat],
            zoom: mapZoom
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });
        myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([long, lat], {
            hintContent: ''
        }, {
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1);        
    });
});

Но так не работает. Как можно это сделать?

Во-первых, перенесите переменные mapZoom, lat, long внутрь функции, иначе у всех карт они будут одинаковые. Во-вторых, высота дива для карт определена?

Спасибо помогло!!!!

Сделал вот так
var counter=0;
    var mapZoom;
    var lat;
    var long;
    $(".map").each(function() {
        counter++;
        $(this).attr("id", 'map'+counter);
    });
    var counter=0;
    $(".map").each(function() {
        ymaps.ready(function () {
            counter++;      
            mapZoom = $("#map"+counter).attr("data-zoom");
            lat = $("#map"+counter).attr("data-lat");
            long = $("#map"+counter).attr("data-long");   
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map'+counter, {
                center: [long, lat],
                zoom: mapZoom
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            });
            myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([long, lat], {
                hintContent: ''
            }, {
            });
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1);        
        });
    });

